# Assigning to from incompatible type warning

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

Assigning to 
      id
 from incompatible  type ''CameraVIewController*'' warning showing at the below code

```
 UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Have you implemented the protocol `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you probably didn't declare that your class conforms to UIImagePickerController.

```
@interface CameraVIewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 17):

Actually, I think the real reason is that you miss the protocol  "**UINavigationControllerDelegate**"

in ***UIImagePickerController.h*** you can see the delegate define:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)    id <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

So if you want to assign delegate like this:

```
picker.delegate = self;
```

the self viewController must implement both **UINavigationControllerDelegate** and **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate**

If you only implement **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate**, you can not find any error literal, but you will get a warning "*Assigning to id from incompatible type ''CameraVIewController*''*", add **UINavigationControllerDelegate** to your viewController's protocol declaration shall get rid of it.

It's a very late answer, but I just met and solved it, hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for showing real reason behind this issue and thanks a lot.

Comment: This was helpful! I didn't know that my class had to conform to both UIImagePickerControllerDelegate __AND__ UINavigationControllerDelegate

Comment: **That is only correct answer thats works for iOS <= 10**

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can fix the warning with a cast:

```
picker.delegate = (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>) self;
```

But you have to implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` anyway.

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me for a similar error except this one - very simple - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to declare private category or class extension on top of your implementation file. For example:

```
@interface CameraVIewController (Private) <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@end
```